# xsltproc, for-each, concatenation, how to skip the last comma?

Tags: xml, xslt

I managed to wrangle up a `stylesheet` file that allowed me to extract a bunch of values from a sizeable `XML` file (export from Kodi) and save them to a `TAB` delimited flat-file. The one thing that irks me is that the `genre` column has a trailing comma on the last element - how can I get rid of that?

A sample of the XML file (`videodb.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<videodb>
    <version>1</version>
    <movie>
        <title>Some title</title>
        <originaltitle>El titulo original</originaltitle>
        <plot>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit. Pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed.</plot>
        <tagline>Lorem ipsum</tagline>
        <runtime>82</runtime>
        <mpaa>Rated R</mpaa>
        <id>tt0123456</id>
        <uniqueid type="imdb" default="true">tt0123456</uniqueid>
        <uniqueid type="tmdb">0123456</uniqueid>
        <genre>Crime</genre>
        <genre>Drama</genre>
        <genre>Thriller</genre>
        <genre>Mystery</genre>
        <country>Spain</country>
        <credits>Juan Peréz</credits>
        <director>Juan Peréz</director>
        <premiered>2001-12-13</premiered>
        <year>2001</year>
    </movie>
    <movie>
        <title>Some other title</title>
        <originaltitle>Ein anderer Titel</originaltitle>
        <plot>Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis. Tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan.</plot>
        <tagline>Id diam maecenas</tagline>
        <runtime>82</runtime>
        <mpaa>Rated R</mpaa>
        <id>tt2345678</id>
        <uniqueid type="imdb" default="true">tt2345678</uniqueid>
        <uniqueid type="tmdb">2345678</uniqueid>
        <genre>Comedy</genre>
        <genre>Thriller</genre>
        <genre>Mystery</genre>
        <country>Germany</country>
        <credits>Max Mustermann</credits>
        <director>Max Mustermann</director>
        <premiered>2002-12-13</premiered>
        <year>2002</year>
    </movie>
</videodb>
```

And the stylesheet (`videogenre.xsl`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>'title'&#09;'originaltitle'&#09;'year'&#09;'genre'&#09;'runtime'&#09;'country'&#09;'plot'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="/videodb/movie">
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            <xsl:text>'&#09;'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="originaltitle"/>
            <xsl:text>'&#09;'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
            <xsl:text>'&#09;'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="genre">
                 <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ',')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>'&#09;'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="runtime"/>
            <xsl:text>'&#09;'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
            <xsl:text>'&#09;'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="plot"/>
            <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
xsltproc videogenre.xsl videodb.xml 
'title' 'originaltitle' 'year'  'genre' 'runtime'   'country'   'plot'
'Some title'    'El titulo original'    '2001'  'Crime,Drama,Thriller,Mystery,' '82'    'Spain' 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit. Pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed.'
'Some other title'  'Ein anderer Titel' '2002'  'Comedy,Thriller,Mystery,'  '82'    'Germany'   'Interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet. Semper quis lectus nulla at. Nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis. Tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan.'
```

And this is the trailing comma I'm miffed about:

`Crime,Drama,Thriller,Mystery,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding an `<xsl:if>` conditional checking position against `last()` without `concat`:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="genre"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> 
   <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Beauty - thank you very much, that worked a treat.